# If a Rails app uses "require 'gem_name'" instead of "gem 'gem_name'" or "config.gem 'gem_name'", will it be faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

because

```
gem 'gem_name'          # Rails 3.0
```

or

```
config.gem 'gem_name'   # Rails 2.x
```

will load the gem no matter what the controller is... will a

```
require 'gem_name'
```

in the controller source code actually make the Rails server run faster because not every controller will load that gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

Stick with keeping your code sane and maintainable by grouping your required gems in your `Gemfile` / `environment.rb`.

I would need to see some well crafted performance data before I'd believe that this would ever make a noticeable difference in a production environment. There are so many other places to optimize first.

Comment: I agree.  This is especially true because your rails app will go ahead and load all controllers when it fires up anyway.